# How to save Excel file in working directory in Win32::OLE

Tags: excel, perl, win32ole

I am trying to parse an Excel file in perl. After I extract the required info from it, I close the Excel file. At the end I am trying to save a new Excel file with a different name in the same directory. But this Excel is getting stored in 'My Documents' folder.

```
use Storable ;
use Cwd;

use Win32::OLE ;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with) ;
use Win32::OLE in ;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new("Excel.Application");
my $excel = $Excel->Workbooks->Add();

my $sheet = $excel->Worksheets(1);
$sheet->Activate();

my $new_file = "Temp_file.xlsm";
my $new_excel = cwd.'\\'.$new_file;
$new_excel =~ s/\//\\/g;

$excel->SaveAs($new_excel);

$Excel->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;
$excel->{Saved} = 1;
$excel->Close;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. What exactly is your question? Where are you struggling?

Comment: The new Excel I have created to store data is not getting saved in the current working directory. Instead I find it in 'My Documents' folder. SaveAs($new_excel) is not happening at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update based on your code. First, you are letting `Win32::OLE` errors to be silently ignored. Instead, set: `$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3` so it croaks whenever something goes wrong. Second, the way you try to obtain an `Excel.Application` instance is not correct. For one thing, if something goes wrong, you will have instances of Excel will remain floating around.

You are also confusing an Excel instance, a workbook, and the sheets it contains. If you did have `$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3`, you would have received a notification of where things are going wrong.

You should also always have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your script. Others will be more inclined to try to help if they know your problem is not caused by some trivial typo.

You also don't need three separate `use Win32::OLE` statements.

The code below "works". Compare it to yours.

Finally, if you are manipulating your sheet via `Win32::OLE`, there is no reason to have `Excel::Writer::XLSX` in your code.

```
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw( rel2abs );
use Win32::OLE qw(in with) ;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

my $excel = eval {
        Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application');
    } || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit });

my $wb = $excel->Workbooks->Add;
my $sheet = $wb->Worksheets->Add;

$wb->SaveAs( rel2abs('temp_file.xlsm') );

$excel->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;
$wb->{Saved} = 1;
$wb->Close;
```

Comment: I have used Cwd package. I can see that $new_excel has the correct path. But the next step 'SaveAs($new_excel' doesn't save the Book1 name Excel file in the target folder with the name I have assigned. Ultimately I can find Book1 file in 'My Documents' folder.

Comment: So, you are saying you did not post the code you ran? Please post *exactly* what you run to illustrate the problem. No more, no less.