# Perl: Can't call method "Worksheets" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, excel-2010

Previously run well on WinXP & Win7 but after move to Win10 it shows "Perl: Can't call method "Worksheets" on an undefined value" error.

```
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') 
         || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application','Quit');
my $Book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($fileName) ;
my $Sheet = $Book->Worksheets(1);
```

Any components need to install?

Comment: Did you not ask http://stackoverflow.com/q/35501825/100754 ? If so, you should at least read my answer. It looks like you tried to copy the initialization code, but instead of using copy & paste, you tried retyping it without understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after activate ms office.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your code, you are trying to call **Worksheets** on the object **$book**. So, the error is effectively telling you that $Book is *undefined* - or more bluntly, there's nothing in the variable you're trying to use.

To find out definitively, you could;

(1) Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your code so perl will be more verbose when it sees common errors.

(2) Add `use Data::Dumper` (at the top of your code) and then on the second last line add `print Dumper($Excel, $fileName);`

(3) Run your program in debug mode by adding `-d` to the command line and then type *help* command.  You need `n` to move to the next statement of your code and `p` to examine the contents of variables.

Looking at what you supplied, the line before the error is an **Open** method call which has probably failed - probably because the **$fileName** variable is empty or contains the name of a file that isn't there.  You can simply check if that's it by replacing

```
my $Book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($fileName) ;
```

with

```
my $Book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($fileName) // die "Open returned an undefined book\n" ;
```

which will immediately exit with an error message if the Open (or anything else on the line) fails.

Comment: I don't think you understand how `Win32::OLE` works and what methods need to be invoked on an Excel instance, so you are just giving general debugging advice, but nothing pertinent to OP's original problem.

Comment: If you say so, Sinan - keep in mind that nowhere in the OP's code (as given) is `$fileName` initialized

Comment: Sure. But if `Open` fails, the reason will not be in `$!`.

Comment: But, of course, there is a way to get the error message.

Comment: But it runs well on Win7 & WinXP, now at Win10 it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Error of "Perl: Can't call method “Worksheets” on an undefined value"

is because your spreadsheet was created in .xlsx you need to save your sheet in .xls and run again it will work!

source:

[Can't call method "worksheet" on an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454615/cant-call-method-worksheet-on-an-undefined-value)

Comment: That's a different method (`worksheet`, not `Worksheets`) using a different module (`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser`, not `Win32::OLE`).